# ejml library use mult() to multiply a matrix by a scalar

Tags: java, matrix, matrix-multiplication, ejml

For example, I want to multiply the scalar, Gamma, by the NxN matrix, A, and return the result as the NxN matrix, B, i.e. B = Gamma * A.

First, I create `DenseMatrix64F A`, `DenseMatrix64F B` and `double Gamma`. Then, I would like to use the method:

```
org.ejml.ops.CommonOps.mult(Gamma, A, B);
```

I get a compiler error that `Gamma` is `double` that cannot be applied to `mult()` in `CommonOps`. The webpage for the `mult` method is [here](http://efficient-java-matrix-library.googlecode.com/svn-history/r228/javadoc/ver0.14/org/ejml/ops/CommonOps.html#mult(org.ejml.data.DenseMatrix64F,%20org.ejml.data.DenseMatrix64F,%20org.ejml.data.DenseMatrix64F)).

I don't know where I am going wrong. Please could you help me solve the problem?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is not a good way to ask a question here. Did you try anything so far to solve your problem? Show your effort first so people might show theirs. Please read [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) as a start.

Answer (score 0):

To perform element-by-element scalar multiplication, use [`org.ejml.CommonOps.scale`](http://efficient-java-matrix-library.googlecode.com/svn-history/r228/javadoc/ver0.14/org/ejml/ops/CommonOps.html).

In your case, try:

```
org.ejml.CommonOps.scale(double Gamma, DenseMatrix64F A, DenseMatrix64F B).
```

In your example, the error arises because the three-argument form of `org.ejml.CommonOps.mult`  expects the first argument to be of type `DenseMatrix64F`, as in:

```
org.ejml.CommonOps.mult(DenseMatrix64F a, DenseMatrix64F b, DenseMatrix64F c)
```

As such, when you pass in a `double` as the first argument you will get a compiler error. Moreover, `mult` performs matrix multiplication c = a * b, which is not necessary for your example.